# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. MVC 4 with Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, sql-server-2008, entity-framework-4

Am using the MVC 4 in VS2010 SP1 installed machine. Am getting the following error

Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.

My WebConfig look like this

```
      <connectionStrings>
    <add name="BuildEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entity.Build.csdl|res://*/Entity.Build.ssdl|res://*/Entity.Build.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=www.xxxx.com,8754;Initial Catalog=xxxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
 </connectionStrings>
```

I had SQL Server 2008 installed in my lap.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have installed a reference to Entity Framework dll in your solution.

Comment: i already addded the Entity Framework and System.Data.Entity in my project.

Comment: If you have find out my comment useful please accept my answer thanks, if you need more help please let me know